# Windows Server 2012 RD services: Cannot connect to a Virtual Desktop

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, vdi

Following a few tutorials I setup a server and installed 2012 RD services on it.

I created a new pooled, managed desktop collection with only one VM which is connected to an internal vSwitch.

From the server itself I can sign in via RD Web Access (https://myserver.lab.local/RDWeb) and connect to the desktop without issue.

When I try to sign in from another physical PC the connection fails.

looking at the Remote Desktop Services event logs I can see RD services is able to authenticate the user and the Connection Broker service is able to redirect the request, but the client never connects.

Looking at event 1307 it tells me it successfully redirected the request:

```
Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client successfully redirected the user LAB\lclaypool to the endpoint DRVDI123-1.lab.local. 
Ip Address of the end point = 10.111.123.5
```

This VM is not directly accessible from outside the Hyper-V server, (e.g. I can't ping it directly from another computer, but from the VM I can ping "out" to any computer accessible to the Hyper-V host) but that's how it is supposed to work right? Because if the VMs did need to be directly accessible like that I would need to bind a physical NIC to every VM correct?

I'm just trying to make sure this is a configuration mistaken and not a misunderstanding of how RD services is supposed to work.

Comment: `Because if the VMs did need to be directly accessible like that I would need to bind a physical NIC to every VM correct`. - No, you just attach them to a External vswitch.  That is a vSwitch with a physical interface attached to the network your clients will be connecting from.

Comment: Attached the VMs to an internal vSwitch so I could run DHCP on the Hypervisor and bind it to only the internal vSwitch so it is only serving VMs. I thought as long as the VMs could "get out" so to speak it shouldn't matter if they are bound to an internal or external vSwitch. Is this incorrect?

Comment: That could work, but you would also need to setup a Remote Desktop Gateway server which could access the that internal network, and would also be on a network that could be accessed by the external clients.  **The broker is not a gateway, or a proxy**.

Comment: Hmm, after reading about RD services I was still a little unclear on the role of the RD Gateway. I'll bone up on this a bit more and update my post after I set it up.